# when i use exel for data driven test, it gives error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\XL FILE.xlsx' thank you

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
import openpyxl

path="D:\\XL FILE.xlsx"

workbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

sheet=workbook.active

rows=sheet.max_row
colms=sheet.max_column

print(rows)
print(colms)
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory: `D:\XL FILE.xlsx` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Klaus D sir i checked already from that way also, same thing is happening.

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: windows @heisAif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

path="C:\xl\Book1.xlsx" that i was forgetting to put xl file name which is Book1.
now it is working

Answer (score 0):

try with different name and remove space:

```
path="D:\\XL_FILE.xlsx"
```

Comment: yes sir i have checked than also

Comment: okay, so my solution is correct...as you miss the name